# jquery slideshow with images from flickr

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flickr

How to load images from flickr for slideshow.

**i know how to create a slideshow with images. whether its possible to load images from flickr with title and description for slideshow. How to do this.**

if there is any jquery slideshow plugin that takes image directly from flickr intimate me.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[this is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/66gVU/)

and I have used the example here on [$.getjson](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: I need a help. In your jsfiddle you used i =10 . what should i do if i need more than 10 images?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WowSlider](http://wowslider.com/index.html#help) for the same.

It Allows you to add external images

Answer (score -1):

try this plugin..i think this is suitable for your purpose..[jquery slideshow plugin that takes image directly from flickr](http://www.userfriendlythinking.com/Blog/BlogDetail.asp?p1=7013&p2=101&p7=3001)